# How to access a small website on localhost from another computer on lan?

Tags: web, localhost, wamp

I have created a small website that has a login system for users on localhost using WAMP. I want to test this website by accessing it from another machine on the same LAN. What all am I supposed to do so as to access the website from another computer??

Answer (score -1):

With the IP of your local webserver or Wamp has, the one that the pc has in your Lan.

Ping your server.

Its very commun that ports are blocked in your local firewall or  some other software, also make sure your Wamp is accepting external connections because they are blocked as default.  Remember Wamp is meant for Local testing.